# Send message to specified channel using SlashCommandBuilder discordjs

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I got this command:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    },
};
```

How to send "Pong!" interaction reply but as regular text message everyone can see and to specified channel ID? (I need to do it as slash command)

Comment: Then use `<Channel>.send()` but you still need to reply to the interaction

Comment: wdym @DragosPV I cant use client.on('messageCreate', message => {
        client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID').send('Hello here!');
    })    because client is already defined in different file bot.js

Comment: You can get a channel by guild too, `interaction.guild.channels.cache.get()`, and I suggest you to make your client a global variable so you can use it everywhere

Comment: Or if you want to send the message to other guild you can get the client by `interaction.client` https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=client

Comment: I made client variable global now it works, ty @DragosPV